# Adding buttons in the dialog's header part?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, button, header

I want to add two buttons in the dialog's header part along with the 'x' icon, but I can only add the buttons at the bottom of it, even after searching for hours, I didn't get any solution of adding them at the top or changing their position from bottom to top. Please help me out.

```
$(function(){
   var winsize = ["width=400,height=500"];
   var newwin = function() {
      window.open("http://www.google.com", "New Window", winsize);
      $(this).dialog("close");
   }
   var hide = function() {}
   var btns = {
       buttons: {
         "+": newwin,
         "-": hide
      }
   };
   $( "#dialog" ).dialog(btns);
});
```

Comment: Can you show the code you have so far?

Comment: Please add this to the original question so it's easier to read and help out.

Comment: where is dialogOpts  being set?

Comment: There is nothing dialogOpts, I typed it by mistake, I've called the var btns in dialog.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's ugly, but maybe a kick in the right direction...

http://jsfiddle.net/AjKFe/48/

```
//create dialog
$("#dialog2").dialog({
    height: 140,
    modal: true,
    autoOpen: false
});

//add a button
$("<a href='#' style='float:right; margin-right:1em;'></a>").button({icons:{primary: "ui-icon-plus"},text: false}).insertBefore('.ui-dialog-titlebar-close').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   alert("click");
});
```

Comment: Thanks a ton, this is exactly what I've been looking for, you are really great :)

Comment: If it's the answer you're looking for, why not mark it as the answer?

Answer (score 0):

I've worked around this by putting regular buttons in the title of my dialog.  of course, you have to wire them up manually and such, so it's not an simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could also do the following:

```
    var titlebar = dialog.parents('.ui-dialog').find('.ui-dialog-titlebar');
    $('<button>-</button>')
        .appendTo(titlebar)
        .click(function() {
            // smth here
    });         
    $('<button>+</button>')
        .appendTo(titlebar)
        .click(function() {
            //smth here
    });
```

or use jQuery icons by replacing "-" and "+" by

```
<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-minusthick">minimize</span>
```